# What is the execution order when both sync and async script tags are used?

Tags: javascript, html

Tell me if I am wrong. The JavaScript code execute as a single thread.

The execution of below JavaScript code will be A,B and C, sequentially right.

```
<script src="A"> .... </script>
<script src="B"> .... </script>
<script src="C"> .... </script>
```

The execution of below code will depend upon the code and the time given to each scripts means first 'A' will start to execute (or 'B', don't know), the execution of 'A' will stop because the time given to it is complete than the others will get the same chance say 'B' , than 'C' and than 'A' again resume and the cycle goes on till the execution of each scripts done.

```
<script async src="A"> .... </script>
<script async src="B"> .... </script>
<script async src="C"> .... </script>
```

But what happen when there are both synchronous and asynchronous scripts occur like below.

```
<script sync src="A"> .... </script>
<script async src="B"> .... </script>
<script sync src="C"> .... </script>
<script sync src="D"> .... </script>
<script async src="E"> .... </script>
```

Comment: That's not how `async` works. See https://html.spec.whatwg.org/#attr-script-async

Comment: There's no `sync` attribute.

Comment: Without async attribute its sync

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `async` attribute merely means that the script will be downloaded *sometime later* and therefore will start executing *sometime later*. `<script>` tags without that attribute will be downloaded immediately and block the rest of the page until the download and execution is finished.

`async` does ***not*** mean that once the script runs, it may get interrupted at any time and another script may start to run. That is cooperative multitasking/CPU scheduling and is absolutely not what happens here. The first `async` script which happens to complete downloading will run, until it is done, at which point the next script will start to run if there's any.

So, yes, with `async` you do not know *when* your script will start executing, but once it does, it is the only thing running until it relinquishes that power (meaning the script and/or function exits).

Comment: What happens if sync and async both downloaded at the same time. like this <script src="A"></script> <script async="B"></script>. Which script will execute first.

Comment: Synchronous scripts will always execute immediately, so in that example A is obviously hit first and will be executed first. B will execute *sometime later*. This is all pretty atomic, there's not a lot of ambiguity: is something already running? No? Okay, then execute immediately. Yes? Then schedule it for execution at the next possible time.

Comment: In case of `<script async src=A> <script src=B>` it is impossible to tell which will come first. If the browser already has `A` in cache and doesn't need to download it, it may start execution immediately before B. However, if it's not in cache, then it's *likely* that B executes first, but still not guaranteed.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't seen anywhere the `sync` attribute that we can use. As far as I know there's only the way we can use the attribute is `async`.

But for your query, you should be using without attribute and this will be synchronous automatically:

```
<script src="A"> .... </script>
<script async src="B"> .... </script>
<script src="C"> .... </script>
<script src="D"> .... </script>
<script async src="E"> .... </script>
```

And now to answer your question,

Asynchronous scripts are loaded in the background while synchronous scripts are loaded in order and affect html and css also.

So, we can not guarantee that using like your exammple order of scripts with synchronous and asynchronous scripts because asynchronous scripts loaded in the background and may be loaded before or after the other synchronous scripts.